# Why I can't change instruction to it's previous values (function call) OllyDbg

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I was trying to revert the changes made to an exe file by some other person. When trying to change assembly to it's previous values - from DD 00B2CD90

[image: from]

to DD 00521088

[image: to]

I'm getting this result.

MOV BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],DL
PUSH EDX

[image: result]

how I can get that call back?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything correct, the bulit-in olly disassembler just tries to resolve opcodes into assembler instructions, but this is only for visual purpose. As long as you are modifying the non-executable section of code (and it looks like .data section) you can ignore the disassembly output generated by Olly. I recommend to modify data like this using the `dump` window.